# Append 2 lists to a list

Tags: python

let's say I have 3 lists:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[]
```

What I wanna do is append these two lists so the result would look like this:

```
c=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: what did you try, and was it `c.append(a) ; c.append(b)`?

Comment: Any reason to not just make it with both from the get go, e.g. `c = [a, b]`?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the result using `c = [a, b]`. Append method is useful especially when you are looping through a list of lists.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Just append normally using `.append()`:

```
c.append(a)
c.append(b)
```

You may as well create the list like so in the first place:

```
c = [a, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

i personally will use:

```
c = [a,b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner solution. You can use the `extend()` method instead. But since the extend method takes only one parameter, make sure to add both `a` and `b` as a tuple value.

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[]

c.extend((a,b))
print(c)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,4,5]
c = []
c.append(a)
c.append(b)
print(c)
```

This should work